# Can't get method name when using decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I suppose I'm missing something obvious, but I can't get the name of methods when I'm using decorators. When I run this code, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute  "__name__"
```

Could somebody tell me how I can get the name of these decorated method?

Thanks

```
def Print(*arg, **kwarg):
    func, *arguments = arg
    print(func.__name__ + "(): {}".format(func=arguments[0]))


class Bob(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def stuff(self):
        return "value from stuff property"

    @stuff.setter
    def stuff(self, noise):
        return noise


class Tester:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dylan = Bob()

    def randomTest(self):
        Print(self.dylan.stuff, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    whatever = Tester()
    whatever.randomTest()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stuff` isn't a function or a method; it's a *property*. The syntax

```
@property
def stuff(...):
   ...
```

creates an instance of the `property` class using `stuff` as the argument to `property`, equivalent to

```
def stuff(...):
    ....

stuff = property(stuff)
```

and instances of `property` don't have a `__name__` attribute, as you've seen.

(It's a little trickier with the setter, since the function and the property have to have the same name. But defining `stuff` a "second" time doesn't override the existing property named `stuff`.)

The individual methods are accessed via attributes of the `property`.

```
>>> Bob.stuff.fget.__name__
'stuff'
>>> Bob.stuff.fset.__name__
'stuff'
```

---

Note another, longer, way to create the same property:

```
class Bob:

    def stuff_getter(self):
        ...

    def stuff_setter(self, noise):
        ...

    stuff = property(stuff_getter, stuff_setter)
    del stuff_getter, stuff_setter  # Clean up the namespace
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer does answer the question I posted. The reason why I'm doing it and why I can't use your solution would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Print(*arg, **kwarg):
    func, *arguments = arg
    print(func.__name__ + "(): {}".format(func=arguments[0]))

class Bob():

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.stuff = s

    @property
    def myStuff(self):
        return self.stuff

    @myStuff.setter
    def setStuff(self, noise):
        self.stuff = noise

class Tester:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dylan = Bob(1)

    def randomTest(self):
        print(self.dylan.stuff)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    whatever = Tester()
    whatever.randomTest()
```

This should work :)